# How to handle urls with ?params in apache redirects?

Tags: apache, redirect

Basically I need to redirect user from:

```
http://www.site.com/page/this?name=jack
```

to:

```
http://www.site.com/page/that?firstName=jack
```

My current rule(obvious doesn't work):

```
  RewriteRule ^/page/that\?name=(.*)$ /page/that\?firstName=$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's my solution:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^/page/this$ /page/that?firstName=%1? [R=301,L]
```

basically, you put a condition in front of the rewrite and that will fetch the param value. notice in the destination url of the rule i am using `%1` and also notice the `?` at the end of it; it breaks without it.